# Android Volley Post Form Array Data

Tags: android, http-post, android-volley, form-data

I am working on a project in which I am using `Volley` as network Library. I need to post array of data to server.

My code to put string params looks like

```
for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
{
    jsonObjReq.addStringParam("params",data.get(i).getId());
}
```

And the data it posts to server is single data

> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="params"
>
> 5810707039473e73135c9b16

Howsoever the data I want to post looks like

> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="params[0]"
>
> 5810707039473e73135c9b16
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="params[1]"
>
> 5810707039473e73135c9b16

I tried to manually create `square brackets` using this code

```
for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
{
    jsonObjReq.addStringParam("params["+i+"]",data.get(i).getId());
}
```

But the data it post looks like

> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="params%5B0%5D"
>
> 5810707039473e73135c9b16
>
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="params%5B1%5D"
>
> 5810707039473e73135c9b16

That's why its not getting parsed on the server.

Help me.

Comment: Why don't you try with `HashMap<String,String>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after reading for `volley` library internal code (I used open source library of `volley`). I figured out the issue and solved it.

For others that are frustrated as I was :

Go to `com\android\volley\toolbox\multipart\StringPart.java`

Go to StringPart.java constructor

```
public StringPart(String name, String value, String charset) 
{
    .
    .
    final String partName = EncodingHelper.encode(name, HTTP.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL_CHARSET);
    .
    .
}
```

and change this to :

```
public StringPart(String name, String value, String charset) 
{
    .
    .
    final String partName = name;
    .
    .
}
```

Now I am working on to create a custom StringArray Class to post array data that will not require modifying it. As soon as I will finish with it, I will post source. Till then it might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all array values as Json Array like this

```
[
5810707039473e73135c9b16,
5810707039473e73135c9b16,
5810707039473e73135c9b16
]
```

or you can pass item separated by comma [first_id,second_id,etc.]

```
5810707039473e73135c9b16,5810707039473e73135c9b16,5810707039473e73135c9b16
```

and then handle them from your side